# Java Classloaders types

Tags: java, classloader

As mentioned in [JVM specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se20/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3):

> There are two kinds of class loaders: the **bootstrap class loader**
> supplied by the Java Virtual Machine, and **user-defined class loaders**.
> Every user-defined class loader is an instance of a subclass of the
> abstract class ClassLoader.

Additionally, we know that at JVM startup, the following class loaders are set:

1. Bootstrap class loader
2. Extension or Platform class loader
3. System or Application class loader

which seems to be contradictory to what is mentioned in the JVM spec as instead of just the bootstrap class loader, there are other classloaders as well supplied by JVM.

Comment: The extension/platform and system/application class loaders are both "user-defined class loaders". That is to say, they are instances of `java.lang.ClassLoader` written in Java code.

Comment: Didnt extension classloader go away as of java 9?

Comment: @NathanHughes: Yes, its  replaced with `PlatformClassLoader` post Java9 with backward compatibility.

Comment: @Slaw: Is it because the Bootstrap class loader is a native implementation and the other two are Java implementations? As per the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F9%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/lang/ClassLoader.html): The Java run-time has the following built-in class loaders:  Bootstrap, Platform, and System.

So what are the criteria for this user-defined vs. JVM provided categorization if all are provided by JVM itself?

Comment: The platform and system loaders are _not_ provided by the JVM. They are provided by the standard library (though the implementations are internal). But something has to start things off (i.e., _bootstrap_ the class loading process). This is done by a special class loader built into the JVM itself.

Comment: Can't accept it as an answer (as its a comment), but that clarifies @Slaw. thanks